# Autodesk Inventor Constraints for Clockwise / Counterclockwise / Dead Points

Tags: modeling

In the YouTube video [Spherical 4-Bar Infinity Mechanism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0erDDuPO7w) by Thang010146, Dead Points are not compensated for by mechanical means. How can **Autodesk Inventor Constraints** be applied to such a mechanism to ensure that it does not change "modes" into a [Spherical 4-Bar Paralellogram Mechanism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQCVg_iXV7U)? I'm **not** looking for a mechanical solution. I'm trying to learn the constraint logic.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5zx74ltkz0v20c/Spherical-Linkage.zip?dl=0) is my own, similar assembly. One of the bars keeps switching direction on me.